# updating my dell-inspiron from 14LTS to 16LTS fails

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dell, inspiron

just wanted to check if I 'm missing out something here. Been trying to upgrade my (factory installed) ubuntu 14.04LTS to 16LTS for a couple of days now. 
When I use the live-CD (usb stick actually) it just boots into a black screen.
When I have the package manager upgrade it seems to work but I can't get past the login screen, the GUI never loads.
When I manually try to force the upgrade I get tons of dependancy errors (most notabilt IMO about PPP).

(was forced to use the 'return to factory state' actually. So I am upgrading from a fresh install).

Should I be doing something special since dell is special or am I just plain stupid? Appreciate your help before my head hits the desk :)

grtx
chris

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black screen when loading ubuntu live usb](http://askubuntu.com/questions/832163/black-screen-when-loading-ubuntu-live-usb)

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After a failed upgrade through package manager, a 16.04.2 install from a usb stick just formatting Ubuntu partition mounted on / worked for me.
Previously, in UEFI I disabled fast boot, secure boot and Compatibility  Support Module (CSM). I don't really know if these changes are needed.

Cheers.