# Black screen when loading ubuntu live usb UEFI mode

Tags: boot, usb

New to forum, first time Linux-installer. 
Moderately tech savvy (tinkerer, can follow instructions to a T).
i.e. I am capable, but hold my hand, talk to me like an idiot.
My issue is exactly as described on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832163/black-screen-when-loading-ubuntu-live-usb/832173), I have tried all suggestions (and others after searching similar posts) but still stuck...
Apologies for double-posting? (ignorant of forum etiquette). 
Asus U46E, Windows 10 Home 64-bit, Intel i5, 8GB RAM, default/no graphics card (Intel HD Graphics 3000) if any of that matters.
Help, please and thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install (16.04 LTS or 17.10 or some other version)? How did you create the USB boot drive (which tool did you use)?

Comment: 16.04 LTS
rufus 2.18, following directions on the Ubuntu download page tutorial

Comment: I selected "MBR Partition Scheme for BIOS or UEFI" instead of "MBR partition scheme for UEFI", because it was default and it's a somewhat old drive

Comment: I just tried booting Ubuntu on a newer machine. Everything ran smoothly. Problem appears to be with the old machine hardware/settings.

Comment: My first guess would be that it should work (taking account of your descriptions in the original question and the comments). But obviously that is not the case. You could start with the following steps: 1. Check that the md5sum matches the listed value at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes, Rufus has a tool for it. ; 2. Download and try some other versions of Ubuntu, for example 16.04.**1** LTS according to this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865 (which is well polished and debugged - I use that version).

Comment: Good that you tested in another computer :-) Now we know that the USB live drive is working. -- You can also try the newest version, 'Artful Dot One', the special version to be released very soon. It is fixed to avoid damages of the UEFI-BIOS system in some computers, and the tests are turning out well, http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/385/builds/164204/downloads

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was considering 'Artul' anyways, I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: Since your computer is old , 16.04.1 LTS (the first point release) is also a good candidate, particularly for older and middle-aged computers. Good luck :-)

Comment: Ok, I tried 16.04.1, 16.04.3 and 17.10. I also tried Mint 18.3. Nothing works. They all boot on the newer machine. The only apparent difference between the two is the Asus runs Windows 10 in BIOS, the newer machine in UEFI. Referencing the original post in my question, I'm always supposed to enable and boot in UEFI. Just to experiment, I thought I'd try booting Ubuntu in BIOS, but I don't even see that option. When I select disable UEFI, the system bypasses USB and boots Windows from hard drive. I'm at a loss. What am I missing? Is it possible my PC simply isn't compatible with Linux?

Comment: More experimenting did the trick. Had to disable UEFI and change boot order in "Hard Drive BBS Priorities". This must be how to load Ubuntu in BIOS mode? Absolutely would not work with UEFI enabled, no matter what troubleshoot I tried (nomodeset, etc.). SOLVED!

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)