# Why do I need to replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset"?

Tags: boot, nomodeset

I have recently installed Ubuntu but could not load it. By searching on Interned I found a solution which works for me but I do not understand it. The solution is taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832163/black-screen-when-loading-ubuntu-live-usb/832173).

In more detail, while I load Ubuntu, I get into a menu which asks me what I want to do. At this point I press `e`. After that I get a screen with some text where I replace `quiet splash` by `nomodeset` and then I press `F10`. After that Ubuntu loads.

Now, my questions are:

1. What exactly am I doing? Why does it help?
2. Can I do something to avoid doing these steps each time I when I wont to load Ubuntu?

Comment: Generally you do not want nomodeset as permanent boot parameter. Its just needed until you install the nVidia proprietary driver from the Ubuntu repository (not directly from nVidia). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: How would it hurt if you kept it permanently?

Comment: @oldfred What if installing Nvidia drivers didn't help?

Comment: @Anna Please post your own question with specs of your system including brand/model & video card/chip.

Answer (score 14):

Short answers for your questions:

1) The option `nomodeset` means do not load video drivers.

2) Install suitable video drivers or read second option of long answer

Long answers:

> 1) **nomodeset**
>
> The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into
>   the kernel. So all the programming of the hardware specific clock
>   rates and registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than
>   in the X driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to
>   have high resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker
>   free transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on
>   some cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black
>   screen. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not
>   load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.
>
> Note that this option is sometimes needed for nVidia cards when using the default "nouveau" drivers. Installing proprietary nvidia drivers usually makes this option no longer necessary, so it may not be needed to make this option permanent, just for one boot until you installed the nvidia
>
> **quiet**
>
> This option tells the kernel to NOT produce any output (a.k.a. Non verbose mode). If you boot without this option, you'll see lots of kernel messages such as drivers/modules activations, filesystem checks and errors. Not having the `quiet` parameter may be useful when you need to find an
>
> **splash**
>
> This option is used to start an eye-candy "loading" screen while all the core parts of the system are loaded in the background. If you disable it and have `quiet` enable you'll get a blank screen.

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

[What do the nomodeset, quiet and splash kernel parameters mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean)

2) To find drivers in Ubuntu, open the menu, type **Drivers**, and select **Additional Drivers**. 
Upon opening, the system will run a quick scan. This will find out if your system has hardware that would benefit from having proprietary drivers installed. It is here that you will find proprietary drivers.

[image]

Source: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-proprietary-graphics-drivers-ubuntu-fedora-linux/

Second option:

**How to permanently set kernel boot options on an installed OS?**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

A text editor will open with the grub configuration file. Near the top of that file you will see something very similar to this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

add your custom boot options to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, so for instance:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then do update your grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Enjoy!

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132