# Graphic Driver Problem Display freeze, tear and jitter Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: intel-graphics, freeze, i915

I recently bought a new PC ThinkPad E580 with Intel and AMD graphics card.

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 in my PC as the dual system with Windows 10. Windows 10 works well but I had a great problem with the display in Ubuntu.

The first time when I went to install Ubuntu (even with "Try Ubuntu" on a live USB), the display would freeze, tear and jitter.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video

*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: UHD Graphics 620
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:148 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff  

*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550/550X]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: c0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f1400000-f143ffff memory:f1440000-f145ffff
```

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:
    Host: fanwu Kernel: 5.0.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
v: 8.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.32.2 Distro: Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) 

Machine:
    Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20KS002BCD v: ThinkPad E580 
    serial: <filter> 
    Mobo: LENOVO model: 20KS002BCD v: SDK0L77769 WIN serial: <filter> 
    UEFI: LENOVO v: R0PET47W (1.24 ) date: 08/29/2018 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8250U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 28800
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 802 7: 800 8: 800 

Graphics:
   Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel
   bus ID: 00:02.0 
   Device-2: AMD Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550/550X] vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A
   bus ID: 02:00.0 
   Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: fbdev unloaded:
   modesetting,vesa 
   resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
   OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) 
   v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.0-devel (git-bcfc9c0 2019-11-20 disco-oibaf-ppa) 
   direct render: Yes 
 Audio:
   Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo 
   driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
   Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.0.0-36-generic 
Drives:
   Local Storage: total: 1.03 TiB used: 10.06 GiB (1.0%) 
   ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Toshiba model: KBG30ZMT128G size: 119.24 GiB 
   ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10SPZX-08Z10 
   size: 931.51 GiB temp: 29 C 
   ID-3: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Generic model: Flash Disk size: 7.48 GiB
   Partition:
    ID-1: / size: 527.19 GiB used: 8.47 GiB (1.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4
  Sensors:
     System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 17408 
  Info:
    Processes: 252 Uptime: 21m Memory: 7.69 GiB used: 843.2 MiB (10.7%)
    Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 8.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.3
    inxi: 3.0.33 

$ uname -sr
Linux 5.0.0-36-generic
```

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
    Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3
    outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
     00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD
     Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
     Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620 [17aa:5069]
     Kernel driver in use: i915
     Kernel modules: i915
```

```
$ glxinfo | grep render
 direct rendering: Yes
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method,
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) 
GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, 
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, 
GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

As suggested in [Why do I need to replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024895/why-do-i-need-to-replace-quiet-splash-with-nomodeset?noredirect=1&lq=1), I added `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub` as:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

It temporarily resolved the problem, but leads to the audio codec module problem when the boost directly jump into the drive self test and block.

I updated the Intel driver, updated the kernel to 5.3, but no use. So does anyone have the same problem as me, and do you have any idea for that? The same problem occurs when I install Ubuntu 18 with exactly the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have random freezes in my laptop with the same process and graphics card (i5-8250U, intel 620)

I found this thread that seems similar, but none of the fixes there worked for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1798961